# Unidentified translation file found for installed mods prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Im working on a store in prestashop, and i tried to import the translation from another store into it (they are using the same theme). To do this i simply exported the files from one store and tried to import them into the other.

What happened is that i received this message:

```
1.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_conf.html

2.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_conf.txt

3.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_verif.html

4.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_verif.txt

5.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_voucher.html

6.Unidentified file found: modules/blocknewsletter/mails/pt/._newsletter_voucher.txt

7.Unidentified file found: modules/sendtoafriend/mails/pt/._send_to_a_friend.html

8.Unidentified file found: modules/sendtoafriend/mails/pt/._send_to_a_friend.txt
```

I have made sure that both of the stores have the same modules installed, as well as the same versions of these modules, but the same message appears.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a Mac `._` are hidden files added by the system when you downloaded and explored the exported files. Then when you uploaded this export to the new site, those hidden files got uploaded too and Prestashop doesn't recognize it.

You should use `dot_clean /path_to_your_extract` command with Mac command line tool. This will remove all those unwanted `._` files. Then you will be able to import those files in your new shop.